# How to read data from a json file when it loads after a time delay, in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

http://mediafile.cloud/e1b227799b1e3e3b

I am trying to read this page using urllib in python but it is reading the data before the time delay of 60 seconds, how do I get the data after the time delay

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

domain=Request("http://mediafile.cloud/e1b227799b1e3e3b")
domain.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
response =urlopen(domain)
time.sleep(60)
html = response.read()
```

Comment: It might be feasible with urllib, but I would say that using selenium will be more appropriate when you want to have interactions with the webpage.

Comment: You might need a python module that renders the JavaScript scripts - maybe `requests_html` or `selenium`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, only one change you have to make:
You have mentioned **capital T here** `Time.sleep(60)`
and **small t** `import time` here
As it is case sensitive, your code will not work. Make it small and it will work fine.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the question, I did use small t and did get the output without errors but the question remains